# Excel VBA - Perform Formula on Sheet Based on Cell Values of Looped-Through Worksheets

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I currently have this code -

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "Uptime" Then
   Worksheets("Uptime").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = ws.Name
```

This loops through all of the sheets and adds the sheetName into Col.A.

What I'm now struggling with is the formula that I want in Col.B.  All of my sheets have a calculated value in cell ET40.

I want to take that value, apply formula `=(ET40/60)/24` and then place it in the corresponding cell in Col.B on my "Uptime" sheet.  I'm struggling with this one.

I've tried - `Worksheets("Uptime").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=(ET40/60)/24"`
But I think that just tries to look for ET40 on "Uptime" which is empty.

I'm not sure how I get the formula in that line of code to look at the current Worksheet on the loop.

Edit -

Full code written with Rory's help

```
Sub Uptime()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Uptime" Then
       With Worksheets("Uptime").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .Value2 = ws.Name
        .Offset(, 1).Formula = "=('" & ws.Name & "'!ET40/60)/24"
       End With
    End If
Next ws


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add in the sheet name:

```
If ws.Name <> "Uptime" Then
   With Worksheets("Uptime").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
     .Value2 = ws.Name
     .Offset(, 1).Formula = "=('" & ws.name & "'!ET40/60)/24"
   End With
```

Comment: Ah cool.  I tried something similar earlier but clearly didn't use the correct formatting around ws.name.
My problem now is that this fills column A, but column B is messed up because of my Rows.count.  I think I may be using it wrong.  Any advice?

Comment: That's excellent.  Thank you very much @Rory, I see how that works.